# What are the parameters that we optimize by using 'Synthesis tool'?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, system-verilog

Sir I am confused, what is the basic difference between  simulation and synthesis and what are the important parameters that we optimize using synthesizer for the ASIC/FPGA design..

Comment: This is a very general question.  You might have better luck doing your own research.  In general, simulation uses a tool that is able to step through the operation of the design in small increments of time, see how the design responds to stimulus, and verify operation.  Synthesis is the process  of turning your VHDL or Verilog code into the low level building blocks that the FPGA uses (Registers, Look-Up Tables, Block RAMs, etc).  Synthesis is needed when you want to actually build your code and program an FPGA.  Synthesis is similar to a compiler in software.

Comment: The first half of your question is easy enough to answer, though not necessarily on-topic here. It is unclear what you are asking in the second half, however. I googled "vhdl simulation synthesis" and found lots of sites that might give you what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Simulation is the imitation of the operation of an FPGA or ASIC design over time. You use computer software, called simulator, to change inputs of the design and observe its outputs. After running sufficient amount of simulations and determining that your design works as expected, you perform synthesis of the design targeting specific ASIC or FPGA. It's somewhat analogous to compiling a C code and compiling it into executable to run on Windows, Mac, Linux, etc.
Synthesis parameters deal with timing optimizations, to improve performance of the design (increase maximum frequency that the design can be run), area optimizations (the amount of FPGA/ASIC logic the design takes), power optimizations (amount of power the design consumes), and synthesis time (it can take many hours to synthesized large FPGA/ASIC designs).